# Genre of "The Edge of Dawn" from "Seasons of Warfare"

Tags: identify-this-genre

https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/The_Edge_of_Dawn_(Seasons_of_Warfare)

I have been thinking it's pop music, but pop music in the West sounds a lot more different and doesn't have a lot of melody to them or at least the type of melody featured in the song above. I need the exact genre and sub-genre, because I am looking for similar songs so I can write lyrics for similar songs.

Comment: Rythem and Blues, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apple music entry](https://music.apple.com/gb/album/the-edge-of-dawn-seasons-of-warfare-single/1488436985)  for the song categorises it as "J-pop".
This is hard to categorise... Melodic pop, but with a club/dance beat also. The [Japanese vocal](https://kagiyama.threebards.com/tag/seasons-of-warfare) seems to emphasise the melody more than the dance beat, compared with the English version.

There are dance music genres, for example Deep House, which combine a melodic vocal with a dance beat, but in both the Japanese and English versions, the melody is the important bit. I think if you want similar music, you will need to look for specific artists: maybe others here can help with suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't the West also produce similar music?

Comment: yes, but hard to categorise...  Melodic pop, but with a club/dance beat also. The [Japanese vocal](https://kagiyama.threebards.com/tag/seasons-of-warfare) seems to emphasise the melody more than the dance beat, compared with the English version